# Delete commit history when undoing commits

Tags: git

I had to undo a few commits by doing `git reset --hard HEAD^^^^`.

After undoing the commits, when I ran `git log --all`, it shows all the commits I have done from the beginning. (It doesn't show all the deleted commits when I run `git log` though) Can I confirm that doing `git reset --hard HEAD^^^^` doesn't delete the commit history? Is there any option I can add so that the commit histories are erased as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`git gc`](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/docs/git-gc). Invoking `git gc` will remove any commit object that does not have anyone referencing it (be it a child commit, a branch or a tag).

Comment: This does not solve the problem. `git gc` will save you some disk space when the commits are unreachable, but it will never change the output of `git log` or `git log --all`: these commands show only reachable commits, which won't be touched by `git gc`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "deleting commit" in Git. Commits are reachable if they belong to a branch, or unreachable otherwise. `git reset --hard HEAD^^^^` moved the current branch 4 commits backward, hence these 4 commits are not referenced anymore by the current branch. But they can be referenced by other branches (typically a remote-tracking branch if you already pushed your commits), hence you see them in `git log --all`.